# Images from android to webservice .net SOAP

Tags: android, .net, web-services, base64

I need send image from android app to webservice .net soap.

method for send image from android:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);                 
byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
String base64String = Base64.encode(b);
```

on .net webservice for receive:

```
public void startApp(string bases){
   Image convertedImage = Base64ToImage(bases);
   convertedImage.Save(Server.MapPath("generated_image.jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
public static Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
 // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
                                     imageBytes.Length))
    {
        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
}
```

Error in Image.FromStream(ms, true);

Parameter is not valid.

Comment: Why are you trying to convert base64string to image? You can simply send byte array to your web service. Don't forget to register your envelope with MarshalBase64 like this: `new MarshalBase64().register(envelope));`

Comment: @Karim i tried, but return error when object serialized. i go look again your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my question with FTPClient.